# Modify Twitter Cars markup from code

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-card

I have a webapp with a bunch of photos. If you go to the base url of the app (say /photos) you see a list of all photos, if you go the url with a specific photo id in the query (/photos?id=34343) the app will show a view of that specific photo.

For each photo it is possible to tweet from within the webapp with the specific url for that photo in the tweet. So whoever reads the tweet can click the link and get to that photo. This works just fine.

But now I would like to add the photo itself to the tweet, and this I do not know how to do. I have read up on [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started) which seems the way to do it (as a Summary Card with Large Image in my case) but afaiu the way cards work is to specify one card for each web page, e.g.

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/> etc...
```

Since I do not have one web page per photo but only a single index page for the entire web app is it still possible to use Twitter Cards for the use case I describe? Or some other Twitter API achieving what I want?

Or am I stuck with text-only tweets here?? 
Thanks!